# How to replace a pattern in brackets Using Vim editor

Tags: vim

Having a file with two feilds which is :(colon) delimited as shown below:

```
Ram:con_[3:4]_aen[52:7]
Rakesh:sync[0:128]
```

I need to convert the :(colon) using vim editor which is in brackets [] to ! as shown below :

```
Ram:con_[3!4]_aen[52!7]
Rakesh:sync[0!128]
```

I tried this but I am not getting the output as shown above.

```
:%s/[%d:%d]/[%d!%d]/g
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
:%s/\([[0-9]\+\):\([0-9]\+]\)/\1!\2/g
```

See that we have grouped the elements `[number1` and `number2]` with `\([[0-9]\+\)` and `\([0-9]\+]\)` and reproduced the first with `\1` and the second with `\2`, putting a `!` in between them.

I have used `[0-9]\+` to indicate one or more digits, but you could simplify to `[0-9]*` (which means zero or more digits) if you are sure that there is always a number between the colon and each bracket:

```
:%s/\([[0-9]*\):\([0-9]*]\)/\1!\2/g
```

Comment: Thank you so much its working

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```
%s/\(\d\+\)\@<=:/!/g
```

`\(\d\+\)` Find a decimal number

`\@<=` Apply a positive look-behind. A positive look-behind means that the previous pattern ( in this case the one above ) is required to match on the next symbol. You can read more how VIM implements this [here](https://jbodah.github.io/blog/2016/11/01/positivenegative-lookaheadlookbehind-vim/).

`:` Match on ':'.

Answer (score 0):

```
:%s/\v\(\[[0-9]+):([0-9]+\])/\1!\2/g
```

`\v` Enable extra regex features

`(\[[0-9]+)` capture group for opening bracket and at least one digit

`:` the colon you don’t want

`([0-9]+\])` capture group for at least one digit and closing bracket

`\1!\2` contents of the two capture groups with the bang you want between

Comment: thanks its working.